# DJANGO cannot import name _compare_digest

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

hello i have python 7.13

DJANGO 1.11.2 version

django-crypto 0.20 version on windows 10.

i want to create a DJANGO app but anytime to try to migrate i take

that error :

```
    from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\crypto.py", line 8, in <module>
    import hmac
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\hmac.py", line 8, in <module>
    from operator import _compare_digest as compare_digest
ImportError: cannot import name _compare_digest
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: Do you have operator installed?

Comment: Try to import operator, it would appear you don't have it installed

Comment: You seem to be hitting [issue 21306](http://bugs.python.org/issue21306), which basically means that your either Python installation is broken. Or you messed up the package path so that `operator` is not the standard `operator` library. Does your application have an `operator` package?

Comment: @Emile where in my code  to `import operator` ?

Comment: Open a terminal, type "import operator", we are saying that should error as it isn't included with your Python installation, like @dhke said

Comment: @dhke  yes i have operator library,i have two pythonpath i think but how to fix it?

Comment: @Mar Well, by first checking what goes wrong. If you open a Python prompt (`manage.py shell` if you've got nothing else) and type `import operator` what does `import sys; print sys.modules['operator']` say? If it's not something like `C:\Python27\Lib\operator.py`, you are getting the wrong module.

Comment: that say me `<module 'operator' (built-in)>`

Comment: i dont have 'operator.py' in my system only 'test_operator.py' and 'fix_operator.py'